# C++ comparing string elements to an int

Tags: c++, c++11

I have number lying in a string variable.
I wanna check if every one of its elements is equal to some value, so I use the **for loop** to loop over every element and use if:

```
        int zera = 0, jedynki = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < liczba.length(); i++) {
            if (liczba[i] == 0) zera ++;
            else if (liczba[i] == 1) jedynki ++;
        }
```

**liczba** is a string.

I know now that I can't do that. I tried to convert this **int** into **char** but still, nothing happened.
What's wrong here? What should I do?

Comment: Could you include the definition of `liczba`? “A string” is not very specific, it can be a C-string, `std::string`, `QString` etc.

Comment: @Melebius it's: std::string liczba from string library

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own posts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you're comparing `int` with `char`

should be:

```
if (liczba[i] == '0') {}
else if (liczba[i] == '1') {}
```

Answer (score 2):

should be used:

```
if (liczba[i] == '0')
```

or using [`atoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi):

```
if (atoi(liczba[i]) == 0)
```